# Is it possible to forcefully map shared folders that you don't have access to?

Tags: windows, network-shares, shared-folders, mapped-drive

My question might come off as pointless, but I assure you I have a reason being asking this,

At our organization, we used to have access to a network resource that was kind of like a central repository. They redid a lot of the network configurations a couple years ago and rolled out new images to all of the computers, and since then, we are no longer permitted to access this resource. All of the stuff that was once there is still there.

Is it still possible to map this drive even though it is no longer being mapped for us? I know I won't have access to it but I still feel the sentimental feelings behind it lingering.

I have tried:

1. **Using the Map Network Drive Dialog** - If I try mapping it this way, it prompts me for the credentials to connect to the share the folder is located in
2. **Using net use** If I try it in the format `net use x: \\server\share\folder\subfolder\subfolder\folder2map` then when I run that batch file, it prompts me for a username and password. I tried changing it to `net use x: \\server\share\folder\subfolder\subfolder\folder2map /USER:%username% /P:No` where %username% is my username on the domain, but then it still prompts for a password. My goal here is not to have access to the resource. But I still want to see it mapped in My Computer. I know this might not make sense, but I have seen it done before. At certain times, I'll see network drives with a red X on them and I attempt to open them it will tell me "Access is denied." But obviously they were somehow mapped even without the proper permissions, so is there some way that I can force the folder to map again? I feel that if it can be done unintentionally when I don't want it, I should be able to map it again forcefully when I want to, regardless of access to the resource.

This is a picture I found online showing what that looks like (what I would like to see for the folder in question):

[image]

I would still have my other drives map normally but then have that disconnect map drive display as such,

I would appreciate any insight on this matter,

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: This isn't specific to corporate IT. I'm just asking how in general you can force a drive map in Windows. This would apply to any version of Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After encountering this situation again, I believe I know when this occurs:

If a drive is mapped with the `persistent:yes` switch or `Keep me logged on` checkbox, then Windows will automatically try to reconnect to the resource again.

If the user is not properly authenticated to access the share (i.e. additional credentials are required) then the share will display as in the picture but with the red X.

This means the drive in question must have been mapped and accessible at one point, in order to display at all, even with the X.

Answer (score -1):

The red X over a drive icon means that a drive is mapped on your host but for another user.

E.g. I keep seeing that on our servers when a specific drive is mounted for the system user only.

I don't think this can be achieved without knowing the actual credentials.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Wouldn't that be an invasion of privacy? And I have seen this happen before with drives I mapped